# How can I use the random module in python turtle?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game like the original snake and I want the "food" to go to random places but I'm not really sure how to get it to work with it in a class. There are some other errors in the code but want to focus on the player and the food right now.

```
import turtle
import random
"""-------"""
t=turtle.Turtle()
s=turtle.Screen()
cube=turtle.Turtle
"""------------"""
WIDTH, HEIGHT=300, 300
DISTANCE=5
"""--------------"""
s.setup(WIDTH,HEIGHT)
"""------------"""
t.width(1)
s.bgcolor("dark green")
"""-----------------"""
class Border():
    def check():
        x, y = t.position()
        if not -WIDTH / 2 < x < WIDTH / 2 or not -HEIGHT / 2 < y < HEIGHT / 2:
            t.undo() # undo error
            t.speed(0)
            t.left(180) # turn around
            t.forward(10) # redo movement but in new direction
            t.speed(3)
"""-------------"""
randint=random.randint
x=random.randint(cube.xcor, 0)
y=random.randint(0,cube.ycor)
"""---------------"""
class Food():
    def block():
        cube.color("red")
        for i in range(4):
            cube.goto(x, -x, y, -y)
            cube.begin_fill()
            cube.forward(20)
            cube.right(90)
            cube.end_fill()
"""---------------"""
class Player():
    def move_up():
        player=False
        while player==False:
            for i in range(1):
                t.forward(DISTANCE)
                t.clear()
    def move_left():
        t.speed(0)
        t.left(90)
        t.speed(3)
    def move_right():
        t.speed(0)
        t.right(90)
        t.speed(3)
"""------------"""
collistion_check=Border()
player1=Player()
s.onkey(Player.move_up,"up")
s.onkey(Player.move_left,"left")
s.onkey(Player.move_right,"right")
s.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your program is a disaster.  As far as your immediate problem with random numbers, this code has an issue:

```
randint=random.randint
x=random.randint(cube.xcor, 0)
y=random.randint(0,cube.ycor)
```

Syntax-wise, this should be something more like:

```
from random import randint
...
x = randint(cube.xcor(), 0)
y = randint(0, cube.ycor())
```

I.e. it's not clear why you set the variable `randint` since you don't use it and `xcor()` and `ycor()` are methods and require parenthesis.

If your goal is to locate the food randomly on the screen, I'd go with:

```
x = randint(cube.xcor()/2 - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - cube.xcor()/2)
y = randint(cube.ycor()/2 - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - cube.ycor()/2)
```

Adding variables as you see fit to reduce the redundancies.  The biggest problem I see with the remainder of your code is this method:

```
def move_up():
        player=False
        while player==False:
            for i in range(1):
                t.forward(DISTANCE)
                t.clear()
```

It's not clear how `player` ever becomes `True` so once you hit the up arrow, you're into an infinite loop.  But I assume you'll focus on this once you get the food issue resolved.